# Docker throws an error on instantiating chaincode in Hyperledger fabric using java-sdk

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

[image]On instantiation of chaincode using fabric-java-sdk I am obtaining the below error. I am running the peers using docker-compose.yaml file.

```
INFO: fabcarss- Chain code instantiation response {
      status: 500
      message: "failed to execute transaction 17e4e74664013463ed52355e380f43a85f1aa5ef44e04ac375342ec4f90d9c72: error starting container: error starting container: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer1.org1.example.com-fabcarss-5: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
    }
```

My peer docker compose is as follows:

```
  peer0org1:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.0
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.role == manager
      - node.id == vbka1smkqlqflno3hfp69rbr7
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=artifacts_default
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: peer node start
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  - 7053:7053
volumes:
    - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You run peers with docker-compose (or just docker) ?
Have you try to modify

```
- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:/{PATH-TO-YOUR-DOCKER.SOCK}
```

Comment: i run peers with docker-compose

Comment: I have added the same in the question.

Comment: General path looks correct (unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock), however `/host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory` indicates docker sock is not available or not running properly?